# mongodb change field type of several documents to array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to change the field type of several documents in one query.

This is some example data. The first example isn't scalable, what if person1 has more than one `thing1`?

This:

```json
{ "name": "person1", "things": { "thing1": { "thingInstanceID": 400 } } }
```

should be:

```json
{ "name": "person1", "things": { "thing1": [{ "thingInstanceID": 400 }] } }
```

I need to do this with hundreds of documents, and there's more than just `thing1`, something like `thing2`, `thing3`, `thing4`, etc. How can I do this?

Comment: It looks more logical "things" to be an array ... , not "thing1" , "thing2" etc.

Comment: I really should revise my database schema.

Answer (score 0):

For "thing1" to convert to array here is an option:

```
 db.collection.update({},
 [
  {
    $addFields: {
      "things": {
         thing1: [
          "$things.thing1"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
])
```

Explained:

Replace the  field with array  using aggregation pipeline( mongodb 4.2+ )  in the update operation

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MaAbeW-uTwC)

Comment: I'm running 3.6.8

Comment: (Never mind, updated to 4.0) @R2D2